# SOS: How to recover my os if i delete /boot signuature in Centos?

Tags: centos, boot

Today I want to extend my `/boot` dir in my centos server.

before i do this, I have three partion:

os was on `/dev/nvme1`, partition is:

`/boot` mounted on `/dev/nvme1p1`

`/boot/efi` mounted on `/dev/nvme1p2`

`/home` mounted on `/dev/nvme1p3`

I backed up /boot dir, then I deleted `nvme1p1` and `nvme1p2`. then add a new partition '`nvme1p1`' (it merge '`nvme1p1`' and '`nvme1p2`''s space)

when i deleted these two old partition, it warning me `Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o:`

then i type `yes` then write to disk. after that, i mounted the new `nvmep1` to `/boot`, then copied the backuped files into this new `/boot`

after that, i reboot, but can find the operating system.

Can you help on this? Can I recover it?

Comment: If what you described is all you did, then `nvme1p1` is now effectively an unformatted partition (because the signature was removed) and the rest of partitions may or may not have changed their numbers (e.g. `/home` might now be `/dev/nvme1p2` instead of `nvme1p3`). And the EFI System Partition  (the FAT32 partition where the firmware expects to find the UEFI bootloader for the OS) that was at `nvme1p2` is now completely gone, so this disk is not bootable until a new EFI System Partition is created and a bootloader installed. Did you at least back up the old contents of `/boot` somewhere?

Comment: @telcoM yes, actually, i backup /boot in somewhere, and after i create new partition, i copied the backup files into new partition and mounted

Comment: @telcoM please see the new describption, i added the information

Answer (score 0):

The "signature" is not directly related to the boot process: it just allows other software to identify that the partition contains an existing filesystem and so it perhaps should not be overwritten (unless the administrator forces it). If you re-`mkfs`'d `/dev/nvme1p1` (or used a partitioning tool that did it for you), you have already created a new signature anyway.

From the fact that `/boot/efi` used to exist, your system apparently boots in UEFI style. You'll need an external bootable media that will likewise boot in UEFI style; if your rescue boot media is booted in legacy BIOS style, it will cause some complications in the bootloader re-installation step.

First, you'll need to boot the system from external media, mount the root filesystem of your damaged OS (by the way, is it on this same disk, or somewhere else?), and chroot into it. The "rescue mode" of a CentOS installation media might do that automatically; if you use some other Linux live CD/DVD/USB, the procedure will be similar to this:

```
mount /dev/something /mnt      # mount the root filesystem to /mnt
mount -o rbind /dev /mnt/dev   # then supply it with /dev, /proc and /sys
mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt /bin/bash          # finally switch to it
```

From this point onwards, all commands in this shell session will see the root filesystem of the damaged CentOS installation (instead of the real root filesystem of the live boot media) as `/`.

Then, since you have re-`mkfs`'d the `/boot` partition, you'll have to use `blkid` or `lsblk -o +uuid` to find its new filesystem UUID, and update it to `/etc/fstab`.
Then you will be able to mount it in its proper place with a simple `mount /boot`.

Next you will have to recreate the EFI System Partition that was at your original `/dev/nvme1p2`. It can be an entirely new partition and it doesn't have to be at the beginning of the disk, but it must exist somewhere the system firmware knows how to access. The type of that partition needs to be set as "EFI System Partition" or ESP for short.

(Technically, the ESP needs to have a partition type GUID of `C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B` if you use GPT partitioning, but nobody wants to deal with that string of numbers, so the partitioning programs use various user-friendlier methods to set the partition type. If using MBR partitioning, the partition type of the ESP should be 0xef.)

The ESP needs to be initialized as a FAT32 filesystem and mounted to `/boot/efi`. Once you have used `mkfs.vfat -F 32 ...` to initialize it, you should again use `blkid` or `lsblk -o +uuid` to find its new UUID and edit `/etc/fstab` to replace the old UUID of `/boot/efi` with it. Then a simple `mount /boot/efi` should suffice to mount it.

The next step would be to reinstall the GRUB bootloader to the disk. If you have access to CentOS package repositories or happen to have the GRUB .rpm file still in `yum`'s cache, `yum reinstall grub2-efi` is probably the easiest way to do this. If that is not possible, you can also use `grub-install`.

The `grub-install` (or perhaps `grub2-install`) will usually only need as a parameter the name of the whole-disk device that contains the ESP; it will rely on the fact that the correct partition is mounted at `/boot/efi`, and will write the bootloader files in there. It will also register the bootloader to the firmware settings.

If your system used Secure Boot, there is one more required step: to reinstall the `shimx64.efi` Secure Boot bootloader. The `yum reinstall shim` command should handle that. Alternatively, you might disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings, at least until you can reinstall the Secure Boot shim.

You may want to check the PARTUUID of the new ESP (with either `blkid` or `lsblk -o +partuuid`), and use the `efibootmgr -v` command to view the current UEFI firmware boot settings: the line that includes the correct PARTUUID should be your active boot entry.

If there's another entry for CentOS with a different PARTUUID, it probably refers to the old ESP you deleted (and is now useless), and you might want to use the appropriate `efibootmgr` options to delete it, to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: thanks telcoM, I am trying, thanks for such detailed guide.